# Fuzebox API available for .net?

Tags: .net

Fuzebox give these APIs.

http://www.fuzebox.com/ignite/api.html

[API GUIDE](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/27206804/Fuze_Partner_APIs_1.3.110119.pdf)

Does anyone know sample for .net or how can I use that in .net?